# Logistic regression when most of variables are strongly correlated

Tags: regression, logistic, multicollinearity

As one of my assignments for uni I need to create a logistic regression model using the breast cancer dataset which is available here: [data](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/breast+cancer+wisconsin+%28diagnostic%29)

I've looking through the data and I see that I have an issue that most of my variables are strongly correlated:

```
> correlation::correlation(cancer[-c(1)], 
+                         include_factors=TRUE,
+                         method='auto')
Parameter1 | Parameter2 |     r |         95% CI | t(567) |      p |  Method | n_Obs
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
V3         |         V4 |  0.32 | [ 0.25,  0.40] |   8.15 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V3         |         V5 |  1.00 | [ 1.00,  1.00] | 362.99 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V3         |         V6 |  0.99 | [ 0.99,  0.99] | 148.32 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V3         |         V7 |  0.17 | [ 0.09,  0.25] |   4.12 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V3         |         V8 |  0.51 | [ 0.44,  0.56] |  13.97 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V3         |         V9 |  0.68 | [ 0.63,  0.72] |  21.89 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V3         |        V10 |  0.82 | [ 0.79,  0.85] |  34.44 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V3         |        V11 |  0.15 | [ 0.07,  0.23] |   3.56 | 0.002  | Pearson |   569
V3         |        V12 | -0.31 | [-0.38, -0.24] |  -7.81 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V4         |         V5 |  0.33 | [ 0.25,  0.40] |   8.31 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V4         |         V6 |  0.32 | [ 0.25,  0.39] |   8.07 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V4         |         V7 | -0.02 | [-0.11,  0.06] |  -0.56 | 0.578  | Pearson |   569
V4         |         V8 |  0.24 | [ 0.16,  0.31] |   5.80 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V4         |         V9 |  0.30 | [ 0.23,  0.38] |   7.55 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V4         |        V10 |  0.29 | [ 0.22,  0.37] |   7.31 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V4         |        V11 |  0.07 | [-0.01,  0.15] |   1.70 | 0.205  | Pearson |   569
V4         |        V12 | -0.08 | [-0.16,  0.01] |  -1.83 | 0.205  | Pearson |   569
V5         |         V6 |  0.99 | [ 0.98,  0.99] | 143.48 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V5         |         V7 |  0.21 | [ 0.13,  0.28] |   5.05 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V5         |         V8 |  0.56 | [ 0.50,  0.61] |  15.97 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V5         |         V9 |  0.72 | [ 0.67,  0.75] |  24.43 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V5         |        V10 |  0.85 | [ 0.83,  0.87] |  38.58 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V5         |        V11 |  0.18 | [ 0.10,  0.26] |   4.43 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V5         |        V12 | -0.26 | [-0.34, -0.18] |  -6.45 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V6         |         V7 |  0.18 | [ 0.10,  0.26] |   4.28 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V6         |         V8 |  0.50 | [ 0.43,  0.56] |  13.69 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V6         |         V9 |  0.69 | [ 0.64,  0.73] |  22.45 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V6         |        V10 |  0.82 | [ 0.79,  0.85] |  34.53 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V6         |        V11 |  0.15 | [ 0.07,  0.23] |   3.64 | 0.001  | Pearson |   569
V6         |        V12 | -0.28 | [-0.36, -0.21] |  -7.03 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V7         |         V8 |  0.66 | [ 0.61,  0.70] |  20.87 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V7         |         V9 |  0.52 | [ 0.46,  0.58] |  14.57 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V7         |        V10 |  0.55 | [ 0.49,  0.61] |  15.83 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V7         |        V11 |  0.56 | [ 0.50,  0.61] |  16.00 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V7         |        V12 |  0.58 | [ 0.53,  0.64] |  17.17 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V8         |         V9 |  0.88 | [ 0.86,  0.90] |  44.82 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V8         |        V10 |  0.83 | [ 0.80,  0.85] |  35.59 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V8         |        V11 |  0.60 | [ 0.55,  0.65] |  17.98 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V8         |        V12 |  0.57 | [ 0.51,  0.62] |  16.32 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V9         |        V10 |  0.92 | [ 0.91,  0.93] |  56.45 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V9         |        V11 |  0.50 | [ 0.44,  0.56] |  13.77 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V9         |        V12 |  0.34 | [ 0.26,  0.41] |   8.52 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V10        |        V11 |  0.46 | [ 0.40,  0.52] |  12.42 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V10        |        V12 |  0.17 | [ 0.09,  0.25] |   4.03 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
V11        |        V12 |  0.48 | [ 0.41,  0.54] |  13.03 | < .001 | Pearson |   569
```

At the same time, one of the key assumptions of logistic regression is the independence of variables, which is obviously not met here. I couldn't find any good sources online or in the course text book of what to do in this case.

My best guess is to start removing correlated variables until I get to the state where only independent variables remain. Is this the way to do it?

EDIT:
I've also checked the Variance Inflation Factor and most of them look very high too:

```
> VIF(glm_fit)
        V3         V4         V5         V6         V7         V8         V9        V10        V11        V12 
911.907192   1.794580 730.245703 118.862196   4.116100  15.913750   5.457273   6.868455   1.776696   9.183906
```

Comment: In what context did you learn that predictor variables have to be independent? Depending on what you’re doing, I dispute this as an assumption.

Comment: I was pretty sure that this is one of the assumptions of logistic regression. For example: "Third, logistic regression requires there to be little or no multicollinearity among the independent variables.  This means that the independent variables should not be too highly correlated with each other."

Comment: @Dave, I do understand that multicollinearity should not affect the quality of the model itself and quality of predictions, but some of the questions I have are in relation to the impacts of various variables in the data on the prediction result and here correlation between variables will be an issue.

Comment: In what context? What are the first two points?

Comment: @Dave, not sure I understand. "First two points" of what?

Comment: “First” and “second” before the “third” you quoted

Comment: @Dave, I didn't think it was relevant to the question and didn't include first and second points: "First, binary logistic regression requires the dependent variable to be binary and ordinal logistic regression requires the dependent variable to be ordinal.

Second, logistic regression requires the observations to be independent of each other.  In other words, the observations should not come from repeated measurements or matched data."

Comment: Please add new information as an edit to the post, not only as comments. Not everybody reads comments!